# How make a Tkinter app OS-independent and run with or without Python installed?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, py2exe

How I turn this code into a software that runs on any PC, or windows, independent of Python interpreter. (I try both 'pyinstaller' and 'py2exe' - using vscode and conda virtual env. Python 3.7.12, without success. The file was created, but dont run):

[image]

Comment: You can use [this](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) documentation to turn your python script into a .exe application that any computer can run regardless of them installing python on the computer you run it on.

Comment: Pyinstaller needs to be run on the same OS the .exe is intended for.  Also you must still have all your files and icons, pictures etc in the folders or accurate paths for the file to work just like any software.  I have used it many times for creating applications to distribute. On windows I even use [this](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to package the files that go with the .exe. It creates a nice setup installer for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Running a python app without python would require compiling it to native code. But then it will not run on any machine anymore.

Comment: The OP didn't ask how to run it without Python, merely without Python *installed*.